# Which metaclass to used to create a class with multiple bases?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say we have:

```
class CustomType(type): pass

class A(metaclass=CustomType): pass

class B(): pass

class C(B,A): pass
```

If we will try this:

```
In [122]: C.__mro__
```

We will got the next output:

```
Out[122]: (__main__.C, __main__.B, __main__.A, object)
```

And the next input:

```
In [123]: type(C)
```

returns this:

```
Out[123]: __main__.CustomType
```

Can you help me to understand how Python decides to use `CustomType` instead of built in `type` metaclass as a factory to create `D`, even when `__main__.B of type 'type'` precedes `__main__.A of type 'CustomType'` in the `C.__mro__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Determining the appropriate metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass):

> The appropriate metaclass for a class definition is determined as
> follows:
>
> - if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then type() is used;
> - if an explicit metaclass is given and it is not an instance of type(),
>   then it is used directly as the metaclass;
> - **if an instance of type() is
>   given as the explicit metaclass, or bases are defined, then the most
>   derived metaclass is used.**

> The most derived metaclass is selected from the explicitly specified metaclass (if any) and the metaclasses (i.e. type(cls)) of all specified base classes. **The most derived metaclass is one which is a subtype of all of these candidate metaclasses.** If none of the candidate metaclasses meets that criterion, then the class definition will fail with TypeError.

The candidate metaclasses are `CustomType` (as the metaclass of `A`) and `type` (as the metaclass of `B`). `CustomType` is a subtype of both candidates.

The MRO of `C` is irrelevant, as it does not yet exist when you are still trying to determine what metaclass to use to *create* `C`.